# Spring Controller return view or empty string to ajax request

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm making an ajax request and I have two situations, where if everything is ok I return a page which will be rendered in a modal else return empty string and don't show any modal at all.

Here is a sample of how should my controller look like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/path")
    public String serve(final Model model)
{
    if (everything_fine)
    {
        return "path_to_page_which_will_be_handled_by_view_controller";
    }

    return StringUtils.EMPTY;
}
```

and the ajax request is something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path',
            error: function (data) {
                //handle error
            },
            success: function (data) {
                 if (data) {
                     // render response in modal
                 } else {
                     // show some other stuff
                 }
            }
    });
```

For the situation where jsp is returned request works fine, when empty string is returned I get 404 and ajax request goes on the error branch when finished. I guess this is because view controller doesn't find any view for the empty string returned, do you have any idea how can I accomplish my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying to return empty path to browser and you get 404. It's normal.
Try to return String with path to controller that returns empty page:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/path")
public String serve(final Model model)
{
if (everything_fine)
{
    return "path_to_page_which_will_be_handled_by_view_controller";
}
return "path_to_EMPTY_page_which_will_be_handled_by_view_controller";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually split this in two requests, one to get the data on which deciding if the modal will be shown or not, and finally request the modal contents if needed.